# Movie/series about people fighting off a fake human to protect a pregnant woman

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm not totally sure if this one was a movie or a series, though I think there's more chance of the former than the latter. By the sound of it, it looks more like a TV movie than a theatrical film.

I probably saw this on the TV at least 11 years ago, and I probably arrived in the middle of the plot. For its time, the movie was pretty modern enough (it was coloured, and the quality of the sound was good enough that, overall, it looked more like a late 90s or 2000s movie). While I saw it it French, I'm pretty sure it was dubbed.

As far as I can remember, all of the characters I saw were white. It looked like everything happened either in an European country, or in North America.

The earliest part I remember is a man running away from another man, in a building (office?) corridor, toward an elevator. In the elevator was a bald man in a suit who was activating the elevator. While the man running toward the elevator was shouting to wait, the bald man simply smiled, not even trying to save the pursued guy (he wasn't trying to hold the door nor anything). But the other guy managed to get in.

Once inside, the guy who was running was feeling safe. Until an arm suddenly pierced through the middle of the elevator door (a bit like the scene where the T-1000 pierces through the elevator door in Terminator 2, except that it looked like a genuine human arm), hitting the bald man on the head. He was badly hurt and was now sitting on the floor. The running man was just shocked of what just happened. As the elevator went down, we saw the arm of the pursuer slowly moving upward, until it reaches the ceiling of the elevator, before removing it.

Though his appearance was pretty ordinary, that's when I realised that wasn't an ordinary man at all.

Later, another scene happened on the roof of a building. Two men were probably fighting that uncommon man. At some point, one of them managed to drop him off the roof. When they looked down, he was laying inside a trash truck, but his face was emotionless. He was just staring back at them, as the truck proceeded to crush him "dead".

After the roof fight and truck crushing event, two doctors were talking about the poor guy who got crushed in the trash truck. They had some pile of meat on the table (probably all that's left of him). But when they checked, they saw a strange unidentifiable piece of metal in there. As they mentioned that they'll contact the binmen to identify what it could be, they left the room with the piece of metal on the table. The metal bit started vibrating, rotating, multiplying. Everytime it vibrated, it doubled in amount. It's as if it was creating more "beings".

The last scene I remember included three women in a somewhat secluded wooden house, using candles as light. One of them was pregnant, the other was a "friend" (or an acquaintance). The third woman was a blonde(?) police officer, probably in her thirties, who joined them mid-way. I supposed that they were hiding away from... whatever it was earlier that got crushed in the trash truck.

Though everything was alright at first, for some reason, the friend of the pregnant lady decided to douse the officer with hot (or boiling) water. Although she screamed a bit, there was only small bubbles of blood on her face. Then it was time for the pregnant lady to give birth.

As the "friend" was assisting the pregnant woman, the officer and many other people (including the one who was formerly crushed by the trash truck) were standing still and watched, as the baby came to life. They weren't threatening them. They weren't trying to kill them. They simply watched. No feeling on their faces. Not a single word. Nothing. I have no idea why.

I don't know if this last scene was the end or if I simply switched channel/turned off the TV on that point.

Comment: Although there's some great description here, this question would still be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum Seems like that list is still useful. After reading through, I found another small detail to add. But I think that's all I could actually remember, for now.

Comment: I wish people would leave a comment to explain their downvote sometime. I can't learn if I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't fret about it. Most questions seem to get the occasional odd downvote for no good reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one episode of a TV series, not a movie. The show you're looking for is [The X-Files](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106179/?ref_=nv_sr_1), specifically the last episode(s) of season 8, though it's a continuation of ongoing storylines from that season (and earlier seasons).

I can't find any clips on youtube (from a quick search) or a useful episode summary on IMDB, so unfortunately you'll have to trust me.

> The earliest part I remember is a man running away from another man, in a building (office?) corridor, toward an elevator. In the elevator was a bald man in a suit who was activating the elevator. While the man running toward the elevator was shouting to wait, the bald man simply smiled, not even trying to save the pursued guy (he wasn't trying to hold the door nor anything). But the other guy managed to get in.
>
> Once inside, the guy who was running was feeling safe. Until an arm suddenly pierced through the middle of the elevator door (a bit like the scene where the T-1000 pierces through the elevator door in Terminator 2, except that it looked like a genuine human arm), hitting the bald man on the head. He was badly hurt and was now sitting on the floor. The running man was just shocked of what just happened. As the elevator went down, we saw the arm of the pursuer slowly moving upward, until it reaches the ceiling of the elevator, before removing it.

This is the FBI headquarters, rather than a generic office building, but this happens almost exactly as described. The bald man in a suit (and glasses, though you didn't mention them) is [Walter Skinner](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0683379/mediaviewer/rm1993103872), played by Mitch Pileggi. The other man is being chased by what the episode synopsis describes as a "Super Soldier".

[image: Arm tearing through elevator door]
*"As Alex Krycek watches, super-soldier Billy Miles tears through an elevator door in the J. Edgar Hoover FBI Building, using only his hand." X-Files wikia page on Super-soldier*

> Later, another scene happened on the roof of a building. Two men were probably fighting that uncommon man. At some point, one of them managed to drop him off the roof. When they looked down, he was laying inside a trash truck, but his face was emotionless. He was just staring back at them, as the truck proceeded to crush him "dead".
>
> After the roof fight and truck crushing event, two doctors were talking about the poor guy who got crushed in the trash truck. They had some pile of meat on the table (probably all that's left of him). But when they checked, they saw a strange unidentifiable piece of metal in there. As they mentioned that they'll contact the binmen to identify what it could be, they left the room with the piece of metal on the table. The metal bit started vibrating, rotating, multiplying. Everytime it vibrated, it doubled in amount. It's as if it was creating more "beings".

This also happens pretty much as described. The "Super Soldier" gets crushed in a garbage truck after being pushed/thrown off of the roof of the building, but is able to regenerate or repair itself later when the "remains" are being examined.

> The last scene I remember included three women in a somewhat secluded wooden house, using candles as light. One of them was pregnant, the other was a "friend" (or an acquaintance). The third woman was a blonde(?) police officer, probably in her thirties, who joined them mid-way. I supposed that they were hiding away from... whatever it was earlier that got crushed in the trash truck.
>
> Though everything was alright at first, for some reason, the friend of the pregnant lady decided to douse the officer with hot (or boiling) water. Although she screamed a bit, there was only small bubbles of blood on her face. Then it was time for the pregnant lady to give birth.

The pregnant woman is the show's other main protagonist, Dana Scully. They've gone into hiding from, as you correctly guessed, the "Super Soldier" that was in the FBI headquarters (and several others like him). The police officer turns out to also be a "Super Soldier", which is why the other woman throws boiling water on her, with relatively little actual damage being caused.

Comment: Just checked the X-files wikia page about Super Soldier, and it seems to be the one.